# Backup tools free trial limitations

Tags: backup, acronis-trueimage, crashplan

I would like to use a backup tool like Acronis or Crashplan in case I encounter a serious problem with my computer and I want to restore it like it is right now. They both have a free trial of 30 days but they do not seem to explain explicitly what won't be functional after the trial period. Is the restore feature still available after the trial period or must my computer die within the 30 days for this trial to be useful?

Comment: You could also use a free tool like [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After the 30 days, the tools will not work without being extended, usually by purchase.

Comment: This is wrong, crashplan free version works after 30 days, with limitations. The worst one, in my opinion is that the backup frequency can be only once daily